# Calling var() from purrr's pmap() returns NA

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, pmap

I am trying to use `pmap()` from the `purrr` package to simplify my code.

I have a list of vectors `x`; all the vectors are the same length. I want to find the mean and variance of all nth elements across all vectors in the list. That is, I want the mean and variance of all the first elements, all the second elements, and so on.

Before the `tidyverse`, I would convert `x` to a matrix and use `apply()`.

```
x <- list(1:10, 1:10, 1:10)
x_matrix <- do.call(cbind, x)
apply(x_matrix, 1, mean)
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
apply(x_matrix, 1, var)
##  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

`pmap()` should allow this without the matrix conversion. `pmap_dbl()` can replace the `apply()` and `mean()` calculation above.

```
library(purrr)
pmap_dbl(x, mean)
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

However, I cannot get `pmap_dbl()` and `var()` and calculation to work. I get `NA` for every variance.

```
pmap_dbl(x, var)
##  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `~` and then with `...` get the elements, and apply the function

```
pmap_dbl(x, ~ var(c(...)))
```

---

The reason for different behavior is the difference in the number of parameters in `mean` and `var`.  In `mean`, after the object `x`, other parameters go into `...`, while in `var`, it is not the case, there is `x`, there is `y` etc.

Comment: Hah! Answered faster than I can refresh (and faster than SO allows me to accept an answer). I knew about the `~`. I should have known about the `...`.